# multiplicar toda una tabla con un numero dispuesto por el usuario

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un formulario de inventario que consulta los articulos de una base de datos con php y quisiera que el precio de los articulos en dolares se convirtiera a otra monedad, tengo un script que funciona, pero solo me convierte mi primera linea, mi primer articulo, y el resto no, si me pudieran ayudar de antemano gracias

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="dolar" id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
</div>
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 5%;">Cantidad</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:5%;">Precio $</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width:5%;">Precio Bs</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 15%;">Fecha de Registro</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 7%;">Editar</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 7%;">Borrar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['producto'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="" id="box2" oninput="calculate()" value="<?php echo $row['dolar'] ?>" readonly="readonly"></td>
                            <td class="bs" id="bs"><input type="text" name="" id="result" ></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>try {function calculate() {
var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
var result = document.getElementById('result');
       var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
        result.value = myResult;


}
} catch (error) { throw error; }


</script>
```

Comment: Repites atributos id  para todos los artículos en el bucle (id="box2", id="result", id="bs") y eso no se debe hacer en HTML. Usa en su lugar un mismo valor de class y luego en el script usas document.getElementsByClassName() para leer todos las celdas en una lista de inputs. Luego actualizas una por una en un bucle.

Comment: estoy aprendiendo aun y me falta mucho por mejorar, gracias por tu consejo, pero no se como hacerlo